# line input not working as expected in VBA

Tags: vba, input, line, eof

I have a text file that I open and attempt to read the individual lines. I have used the same code before on other files with no problem, but for some reason, this particular file is strange. When I do the following command;

```
Line Input #1, read_string
```

the string read_string contains the entire sequence of each line in the file concatenated together. When I look at the special chararcters of the file I do see a cariage return. But just so you know what the file looks like, here are the first two lines (daniweb formatting is too strange to print text here),

```
k_arr[8'h1C]= {10'b001111_0100,10'b110000_1011} ;
k_arr[8'h1C]= {10'b001111_0100,10'b110000_1011} ;
```

Anybody know how I can read each line? apparently line input doesnt work for this file.

Comment: Probably the file is CR delimited not CR/LF delimited as expected by VBA.  You should either rewrite your vba code to split on CR or use a utility to save the file with CR/LF.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Dim lines() As String
lines = Split(read_string, vbCr) 'splitting with Carriage Return delimiter
'did it work?
Debug.Print lines(1)
Debug.Print lines(2)    Dim lines() As String
```

Each element of the `lines` array should now contain one line of your text file.

If it didn't work, try with another delimiter instead of `vbCr`, e.g. `vbLf` (line feed).